libclang CXTranslationUnit_DetailedPreprocessingRecord doesn't affect parse
While trying to use the C libclang bindings to parse some sources, I have found that preprocessor directives do not show up in the AST.
Following recommendations from this previous question, and calling clang_parseTranslationUnit with the CXTranslationUnit_DetailedPreprocessingRecord flag does not resolve the issue.
I have been able to reproduce the issue with the following demo code (not cleaning up objects is intentional), which is a simple driver that sources its compile arguments from a compile_commands.json database located in the same directory as the tool for the file passed in as argv[1].
#include <clang-c/Index.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
  CXCompilationDatabase db = clang_CompilationDatabase_fromDirectory(".", nullptr);
  CXCompileCommands cmds = clang_CompilationDatabase_getCompileCommands(db, argv[1]);
  CXCompileCommand cmd = clang_CompileCommands_getCommand(cmds, 0);

  std::vector<const char *> args;
  for (int i = 0; i < clang_CompileCommand_getNumArgs(cmd); ++i) {
    args.push_back(clang_getCString(clang_CompileCommand_getArg(cmd, i)));
  }

  CXTranslationUnit tu;
  clang_parseTranslationUnit2FullArgv(index, nullptr, args.data(), args.size(),
                                      nullptr, 0, CXTranslationUnit_DetailedPreprocessingRecord, &tu);
  clang_visitChildren(clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(tu), visitor, nullptr);
}

The visitor function is a function that prints out some basic information about any preprocessor directives it encounters.
CXChildVisitResult visitor(CXCursor cursor, CXCursor parent,
                           CXClientData client_data) {
  if (clang_Location_isFromMainFile(clang_getCursorLocation(cursor)) == 0)
    return CXChildVisit_Continue;

  CXCursorKind kind = clang_getCursorKind(cursor);
  if (kind >= CXCursor_FirstPreprocessing &&
      kind <= CXCursor_LastPreprocessing) {
    CXTranslationUnit tu = clang_Cursor_getTranslationUnit(cursor);
    CXFile file = clang_getFile(tu, nullptr);

    unsigned line, column;
    clang_getExpansionLocation(
        clang_getRangeStart(clang_getCursorExtent(cursor)), &file, &line,
        &column, nullptr);
    std::cout << clang_getCString(clang_getFileName(file)) << ":" << line << ":"
              << column << " ["
              << clang_getCString(clang_getCursorKindSpelling(kind)) << "]\n";
  }
  return CXChildVisit_Recurse;
}

The issue is that the preprocessor directives do not show up in the AST, despite there not being other errors.
I have tried appending -Xclang -detailed-preprocessing-record to the compile arguments, as suggested in the linked question, which does not resolve the issue.
Any help would be appreciated.

After looking at libclang sources, I have found the source of my problem.
The problem was with the compile command arguments being passed to clang_parseTranslationUnit2FullArgv.
Specifically, although the command in the compile_commands.json database looked normal, something like this, with paths replaced with placeholders:
...
{
  "directory": "<build_dir>",
  "command": "/opt/local/libexec/llvm-16/bin/clang++ -I<...> -g -std=c++20 <...> -o <output_dir>/bindings.cpp.o -c <input_dir>/bindings.cpp",
  "file": "<input_dir>/bindings.cpp",
  "output": "<output_dir>/bindings.cpp.o"
},
...

The compile command found by clang_CompilationDatabase_getCompileCommands was not the same as the one in the compile_commands.json database.
Crucially, printing out the compile command arguments in the driver code showed something like this:
Suitable compile command for <input_dir>/bindings.cpp found in compilation database: /opt/local/libexec/llvm-16/bin/clang++ --driver-mode=g++ -I<...> -g <...> -c -std=c++20 -- <input_dir>/bindings.cpp 

which is slightly different from the one in the database by not including the output file argument and adding -- before the input file.
This is enough to break libclang's parsing.
Examining the implementation of clang_parseTranslationUnit2FullArgv in libclang's sources, we see that in clang_parseTranslationUnit_Impl called by the parser, arguments are appended to the provided command line arguments according to the options passed to the parser:
// The 'source_filename' argument is optional.  If the caller does not
// specify it then it is assumed that the source file is specified
// in the actual argument list.
// Put the source file after command_line_args otherwise if '-x' flag is
// present it will be unused.
if (source_filename)
  Args->push_back(source_filename);

// Do we need the detailed preprocessing record?
if (options & CXTranslationUnit_DetailedPreprocessingRecord) {
  Args->push_back("-Xclang");
  Args->push_back("-detailed-preprocessing-record");
}

This is an obvious problem when the -- separator is present in the user-provided compile command arguments, which forces any arguments after it to be treated as positional input file arguments.
Thus, libclang does not see the modified argument to enable detailed preprocessing records, and the preprocessor directives are not included in the AST.
Similarly, this explains why manually appending -Xclang -detailed-preprocessing-record to the compile command arguments did not work, as it did exactly the same thing as the libclang does internally.
The solution that worked for me is to remove the -- separator from the compile command arguments libclang finds in the compilation database and that are passed to clang_parseTranslationUnit2FullArgv.
With respect to the demo, that would mean changing the argument conversion step to:
std::vector<const char *> args;
for (int i = 0; i < clang_CompileCommand_getNumArgs(cmd); ++i) {
  const char* arg = clang_getCString(clang_CompileCommand_getArg(cmd, i));
  if (strcmp(arg, "--") != 0)
    args.push_back(arg);
}

TL;DR
Libclang's clang_CompilationDatabase_getCompileCommands does not return compile commands suitable for clang_parseTranslationUnit2FullArgv, which does not support the -- separator.
Removing the -- separator from the compile command arguments passed to clang_parseTranslationUnit2FullArgv resolves the issue.

@ScottMcPeak thanks for the suggestion, edited for clarity.
